# How to sum grouped values from a table? For example I will sum the name?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How do I sum grouped values from a table? For example I will sum the name?

this values :

```
2.997,
7.497
```

return : result!

I already have a function which delivers the whole sum this works fine.   But I have don't a clue how to solve this problem ![enter image description here][1]

here is my function for the whole sum!

```
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".overviewTaxes").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        // add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
        }
    });
    $( ".globalTaxSum" ).html(sum);
}


<tbody>
   <?php foreach ($overviews as $overview): ?>
      <tr>
         <td >
            <?php echo $overview["forename"] . " " . $overview["surname"]; ?>
         </td>
         <td>
            <?php echo $overview["article"]; ?>
         </td>
         <td>
            <?php echo $overview["articleprice"]; ?>
         </td>
         <td class="overviewTaxes">
            <?php

               $ps = $overview["articleprice"] * 0.3; //flat rate
               echo round($ps, 3) ;
            ?><br/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Thanks for help.

Best regards
Marc Kevin

Comment: Could you please add some HTML markup. Also, your picture wasn't uploaded. What was your error?

Comment: It might be that .length only works on strings, so your if statement will never be true

Comment: please remove `php` tag I dont see any php code here

Comment: @dparoli, actually, there is a `foreach` in php.

Comment: yeah @LorenzoMarcon, cause it was added some minutes ago

Comment: what your problem here ?

Comment: @JYoThI, i need the total 'flat rate' from every person under the single flat rates in the table. That means, that i need a new row under every person.

I can't share a picture, because i don't have enough points.

Comment: i mean flat rate tax.